# How to return 0 rows in specific case statement using PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
time as "time", 
tag as "tag", 
case when tag = 'KEB1.DB_IN.01.STATUS_CMD.A_LIM_32A' THEN 32 
     when tag = 'KEB1.DB_IN.01.STATUS_CMD.A_LIM_63A' THEN 63 
     when tag = 'KEB1.DB_IN.01.STATUS_CMD.A_LIM_80A' THEN 80 
     when tag = 'KEB1.DB_IN.01.STATUS_CMD.A_LIM_125A' THEN 125 
     when tag = 'KEB1.DB_IN.01.CONFIG.ENABLE' THEN 0 
end as "value" 
FROM metrics 
WHERE "time" BETWEEN '2021-07-07T02:37:37.245Z' AND '2021-07-07T08:37:37.245Z'
AND container = '1234' 
AND ((tag = 'KEB1.DB_IN.01.STATUS_CMD.A_LIM_32A' OR tag = 'KEB1.DB_IN.01.STATUS_CMD.A_LIM_63A' OR tag = 'KEB1.DB_IN.01.STATUS_CMD.A_LIM_80A' OR tag = 'KEB1.DB_IN.01.STATUS_CMD.A_LIM_125A') AND value = 1 ) 
OR (tag = 'KEB1.DB_IN.01.CONFIG.ENABLE' and value = 0) 
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3 
ORDER BY time desc 
LIMIT 1
```

That results in:

[image]

Or the following results are also possible:

```
2021-07-06 17:00:00 - KEB1.DB_IN.01.STATUS_CMD.A_LIM_32A - 1 or 0
2021-07-06 17:00:00 - KEB1.DB_IN.01.STATUS_CMD.A_LIM_63A - 1 or 0
2021-07-06 17:00:00 - KEB1.DB_IN.01.STATUS_CMD.A_LIM_80A - 1 or 0
2021-07-06 17:00:00 - KEB1.DB_IN.01.STATUS_CMD.A_LIM_125A - 1 or 0
```

When I get the results listed in the text above, it should return this text and this works as we speak. However when I'm getting returned the data displayed in the image I'm trying to retrieve nothing (0 rows). How can I achieve this?

Comment: I don't get you... Do you want to "translate" tag into proper value? For example: `KEB1.DB_IN.01.STATUS_CMD.A_LIM_32A` => 32, `KEB1.DB_IN.01.STATUS_CMD.A_LIM_63A` => 63, etc. Am i right?

Comment: Why would `KEB1.DB_IN.01.STATUS_CMD.A_LIM_32A` have 0 or 1 in third column?

Comment: Take a look at this [db_fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=38e53eca9fd9a08f284594f072a380c7). I'd suggest to add helper table to return proper value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to return an empty result set if the most recent `tag` is `KEB1.DB_IN.01.CONFIG.ENABLE` and `value` is `0`.

If that's the case then you can do it like this:

```
with tab as (
    SELECT 
    time as "time", 
    tag as "tag", 
    case when tag = 'KEB1.DB_IN.01.STATUS_CMD.A_LIM_32A' THEN 32 
         when tag = 'KEB1.DB_IN.01.STATUS_CMD.A_LIM_63A' THEN 63 
         when tag = 'KEB1.DB_IN.01.STATUS_CMD.A_LIM_80A' THEN 80 
         when tag = 'KEB1.DB_IN.01.STATUS_CMD.A_LIM_125A' THEN 125 
         when tag = 'KEB1.DB_IN.01.CONFIG.ENABLE' THEN 0 
    end as "value",
    dense_rank() over(order by time desc) rn
    FROM metrics 
    WHERE "time" BETWEEN '2021-07-07T02:37:37.245Z' AND '2021-07-07T08:37:37.245Z'
    AND container = '1234' 
    AND ((tag = 'KEB1.DB_IN.01.STATUS_CMD.A_LIM_32A' OR tag = 'KEB1.DB_IN.01.STATUS_CMD.A_LIM_63A' OR tag = 'KEB1.DB_IN.01.STATUS_CMD.A_LIM_80A' OR tag = 'KEB1.DB_IN.01.STATUS_CMD.A_LIM_125A') AND value = 1 ) 
    OR (tag = 'KEB1.DB_IN.01.CONFIG.ENABLE' and value = 0) 
    GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
)
select time, tag, value from tab
where not exists (select 1 from tab where rn = 1 and tag = 'KEB1.DB_IN.01.CONFIG.ENABLE' and value = 0)
```

Comment: Hi, This is correct. I've tried your query and I'm getting an error at line 15 on the WHERE clause.

Comment: @NielsStenden I fixed it, check again

Comment: Its almost working, however when I do want an result, there column "rn" is in the row, this causes a problem with the integration of my front-end platform. Is there a way to just show the columns: time, tag and value?

Comment: @NielsStenden yes, check again